# Select three rows when two of them need to be unique (SQL)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

First of all I am using Oracle 10g Express

So there are three columns I want to select:

[domain_name] [index_path] [collection_name]

Now there are two columns that I want to be unique:

[domain_name] [index_path]

So my issue is how do I basically:

```
select unique domain_name, index_path from TABLENAMEHERE
```

while also selecting the column [collection_name]

Comment: Do you need a unique value of domain_name, AND a unique value of index_path, or a unique COMBINATION of the two?

Comment: unique COMBINATION of the two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are multiple rows for some combinations of domain_name, index_path then what value of collection_name would you want to see from those rows? If you don't mind which value then do:

```
SELECT domain_name, index_path, MIN(collection_name) collection_name
FROM TABLENAMEHERE
GROUP BY domain_name, index_path;
```

Comment: What if I was to say there is another column named [gen_timestamp] it is indeed a time stamp and I want to select the row that has the most recent time stamp.

Comment: @jacobnlsn: In that case it's kind of unfortunate you didn't metion the requirement in your original post. Maybe you could edit it to explain your full requirements.

Comment: see my answer below - analytics!

Answer (score 1):

```
select domain_name, index_path, collection_name
  from my_table outr
       inner join 
         (select domain_name, index_path, collection_name, 
                 max(gen_timestamp) 
                    over (partition by domain_name, index_path) gen_timestamp
            from my_table) innr
 where outr.domain_name = innr.domain_name
   and outr.index_path  = innr.index_path
   and outr.collection_name = innr.collection_name
   and outr.gen_timestamp   = innr.gen_timestamp
```

Comment: Looks good, logically speaking it should work, but after (and before) I switch out "my_table" with my actual table name.  I get this error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 1

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `unique` with `distinct` in your query.

Oh...

Then it should be like this:

```
select [domain_name], [index_path], min([collection_name]) 
from TABLENAMEHERE
group by [domain_name], [index_path]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the domain_name and index_path and include ONE (min or max) value of collection_name per group.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I want to do, how does one do that?